# Permanent Hats for GIS

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hats

Any chance of making Hats a permanent feature for GIS?

Perhaps even make up hats specific to GIS in some fashion (pun intended).

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately, no. The hats are not permanent.  Winter Bash hats are always temporary that get put back in the box when hat season is over.

If you want hats to remain, then you should wear a hat, take a screenshot of your avatar with it and change your avatar as you'd like. But we've got no plans to make hats permanent.

Comment: I'm not that inclined to permanent hats, but I wonder about the rationale for the decision. Site load? An "unprofessional" feel? Lack of novelty for the silly season? Or something else.

Comment: @BradHards It's a way to have a bit of fun at the end of each year, making them permanent would take that away.